# DataTables warning (table id = 'exercises-list'): Requested unknown parameter '3' from the data source for row 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am going crazy over this error that is coming up.

I have the following table view which is using jquery datatables.

```
var exercises = $('#exercises-list').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": false },
      null, null,  null,  null, 
      { "bSortable": false }
    ] } ); 

<table id="exercises-list" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Title</th>
                 <th>Created By</th>
                 <th></th>
             </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody> 
              <tr>
                  <th>title</th>
                  <th>name</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
       </tbody> 
</table>
```

I have a feeling that the error is due to this :

```
null, null,  null,  null,
```

I had got this working with 1 field in table, but everything went haywire when i added fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of columns in HTML and the aoColumns array length do not match.
From DataTables documentation,

> aoColumns: If specified, then the length of this array must be equal
>   to the number of columns in the original HTML table.

http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns